# Raw Ajax vs JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

My seminar topic is Raw AJAX vs JQuery AJAX. My first question is that Raw AJAX is same as Normal Ajax or is it different?.
Give me the reference link to study about Raw AJAX and JQuery AJAX. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have little knowledge in AJAX. But, I don.t know about Raw AJAX and JQuery AJAX. So, help me.

Comment: Is the Raw AJAX is same as Normal AJAX or not?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src/ajax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing called raw ajax. Ajax is a simple XMLHttpRequest in javascript. You need to create the required object and handle the callbacks. jQuery provides a wrapper over the same thing and makes doing Ajax request a breeze. It handles browser specific ajax code so that you can concentrate on the usage rather than implementation.

You can learn more on Simple Ajax here : http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp , http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

jQuery Ajax : http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp , http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/